# How to view relationships and backreferences generated by SQLAlchemy Automap

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy [Automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) with reflection to connect to an existing database. Some of the relationships work properly and some do not. I'd like a way to audit the results of `prepare()` so I can better understand what I'm working with. How can I view the relationship objects produced after I run `prepare()`?

`Base.classes.<classname>.__table__` shows the tables and included `ForeignKey` objects as described in the documentation but no relationships are backreferences are included here, probably because it's at the `Table` level rather than the `class` level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what AutoMap does. Inspect may help. not sure

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
relations = inspect(Base.classes.<classname>).relationships.items()
```

Comment: Perfect. Just added items() call to the end and it's immediately iterable and printable.